# Cisco SNMP OID for track/SLA monitor

Tags: cisco, ios, oid

I have Cisco 3600 router, and a few SLA monitors configured. Based on these monitors, I make a decision where to route users (basically a failover).

It works very smooth and nice, to the point where no one notices when one of the connections goes down. I just discovered that one of our internet connections was down for about a week!

So naturally I wanted to set up a monitor for that condition. Natural choice is SNMP. I Started digging for OIDs, and have a really hard time figuring out what would be the correct OID (how to find that OID) for my SLA monitor. Found OIDs for interface, but interface is always up, even if the connection is down (unless it is physically unplugged ot power is off on the other end).

So the question is how can I find out what would be an OID for SLA monitor so that I can see the same things "show track" does on a remote computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the command `snmp-server enable traps rtr` to enable traps regarding SLA Monitor and the RTTMON MIB to pull data.
I recommand you to read 
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/technologies/tk648/tk362/tk920/technologies_white_paper0900aecd8017f8c9.html (search for snmp) and http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&mibName=CISCO-RTTMON-MIB